# "Стороны-участники сделки". Как пишется?

Tags: дефис-тире

Как верно: стороны-участники сделки или стороны – участники сделки?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правильно: **стороны — участники сделки.**

***Участники сделки*** — это обособленное **с помощью тире** распространенное приложение, ***стороны*** — определяемое слово, второе тире опускается.

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111

10. При обособлении приложений вместо запятой употребляется тире.Примечание. Одно тире (первое или второе) опускается:

На совещании министров иностранных дел **стран — членов Организации американских государств** выступил министр иностранных дел Кубы (Газ.);